# Add and remove default and hover background images on hover through ACF

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This is my very first thread, I'll try to be as precise as possible.
I'm very new to working with php, and my current project is therefor quite a challenge.

I have 2 products, I would like to be able to, through ACF, to exchange both the default BG image and the hover image.

ATM I can exchange the hover, but its visible at all time.
If I add an image through the wysiwyg editor, it wont set as bg image, but on top of the content.

Heres what I have:

- [These are the two products. The left one has the hover bg img, shown at all time. The right one doesnt have any for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc6os.png)
- [Here you can see the ACF on the relevant page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRzTP.png)
- [Here is what it looks like, if I add an image through the wysiwyg editor (the hover img shows in the background)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af13n.png)
- [Here is my css, for the products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgQJz.png)

Here what the code looks like:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Variables
 */

$introductiontitle = get_sub_field('introduction_title');
$introductionsubtitle = get_sub_field('introduction_subtitle');
$introductionsubtitle2 = get_sub_field('introduction_subtitle_2');
$hover_image1 = get_sub_field('hover_element_1_background');
$hover_image2 = get_sub_field('hover_element_2_background');

<!--  Introduction
-------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="container-fluid pt-5 pb-8">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center mb-3">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold mb-3">
                <?php echo $introductiontitle; ?>
            </h1>
            <p>
                <?php echo $introductionsubtitle; ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php echo $introductionsubtitle2; ?>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="col-12 product chart py-5 mb-3 bg-center bg-cover"
            <?php if ($hover_image1) { ?>
                    style="background-image: url(<?php echo $hover_image1 ?>"
                <?php } ?>
            >
                <?php the_sub_field('hover_element_1'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="col-12 product chart py-5 mb-3 bg-center bg-cover"
                <?php if ($hover_image2) { ?>
                    style="background-image: url(<?php echo $hover_image2 ?>"
                <?php } ?>
            >
                <?php the_sub_field('hover_element_2'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this all made sense!? Otherwise just let me know, and I'll explain it better.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you don't have the `:hover` pseudo class? like `.whateverClass:hover{background-image: url(<?php echo $hover_image1 ?>;}` And I don't think that a pseudo class can be written with inline styling. I guess that you could write dynamic css, by adding a class to the div, with the name of the image or something, and target that with `<style>` in your current php file?

Comment: another idea, could be to use a little js. like `onMouseOver="this.style.color='#0F0'"
   onMouseOut="this.style.color='#00F'"`would change the color same as a hover effect.

Comment: @Stender, "by adding a class to the div, with the name of the image or something, and target that with <style> in your current php file"
- Would it then still be possible to dynamically change the img from the WP page (ACF)?

In my syle.css I have this:

product:hover span.add-label {
  display: block; }

.product .content-hover {
  display: none; }

.product:hover .content {
  display: none; }

.product:hover .content-hover {
  display: block; }

Comment: You can't do it in style.css - but you could do it in a style block above the element

Answer (score 0):

I would've posted a comment for clarification but don't have enough points for that yet so decided I'd post an answer as it might be what you're trying to achieve.

Using a combination of layered elements and opacity you should be able to achieve an effect where the background image changes.

Here's an example using solid colours, but they can easily be changed to other elements (e.g. your custom background images, and images):
https://codepen.io/epsilon42/pen/NBNVad

HTML:

```
  <div class="product" style="background: #ccc;"><!-- change inline style to to ACF initial background-image -->
    <div class="hover-background" style="background: #666;"><!-- change inline style to to ACF hover background-image --></div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h2>test</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
      <div class="icon">
        <div class="initial-icon" style="background: #f00;"><!-- change this div to initial <img> --></div>
        <div class="hover-icon" style="background: #b4d455;"><!-- change this div to hover <img> --></div>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.product {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.product .hover-background,
.product .copy {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.product .hover-background {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s all ease-in;
}
.product .copy {
  text-align: center;
}
.product .copy .icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.product .copy .icon .initial-icon,
.product .copy .icon .hover-icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.product .copy .icon .hover-icon {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s all ease-in;
}
.product:hover .hover-background {
  opacity: 1;
}
.product:hover .copy .icon .hover-icon {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

You will need to adjust the CSS a bit to suit your situation.

Comment: Wow thanks alot @epilson42.
That's a massive help!
Im gonna try that out as soon as im home. Ill let you know later, if it worked :)

Also Stender thank you very much for you reply. I didnt quite manage to solve it, using your first solution - BUT im pretty sure, its just me who did it wrong...